# Python Pandas equivalent to the excel fill handle?

Tags: python, pandas, autofill

Is there a Pandas function equivalent to the MS Excel fill handle?

[image: Fill Handle from MS Excel]

It fills data down or extends a series if more than one cell is selected.  My specific application is filling down with a set value in a specific column from a specific row in the dataframe, not necessarily filling a series.

Comment: Not sure what the analog would be here. The fill handle is a graphical feature and a Series is an in-memory data structure.

Comment: Python is not drag and drop as far as I know...

Comment: `pd.ffill()` is probably the closest equivalent, though it's specifically for `NaN` values. If you're trying to fill values according to some other convention, it needs to be code-based

Comment: Wow, I didn't even finish writing the question before I had 3 comments here.  Impressive.  I was hoping for something that will overwrite whatever is in that row with the new desired value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple function essentially does what I want.  I think it would be nice if ffill could be modified to fill in this way...

```
def fill_down(df, col, val, start, end = 0, interval = 1):
    if not end:
        end = len(df)
    for i in range(start,end,interval):
        df[col].iloc[i] += val
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

As others commented, there isn't a GUI for pandas, but [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) gives the functionality you're looking for. You can also use ffill with groupby for more powerful functionality. For example:

```
>>> df
      A     B
0     12    1
1     NaN   1
2     4     2
3     NaN   2
>>> df.A = df.groupby('B').A.ffill()
      A    B
0     12   1
1     12   1
2     4    2
3     4    2
```

Edit: If you don't have NaN's, you could always create the NaN's where you want to fill down. For example:

```
>>> df
Out[8]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  3
2  4  5

>>> df.replace(3, np.nan)
Out[9]: 
    A    B
0  1.0  2.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't have any NaNs?